# RandomGenerated Map with Path from start to end

Tags: actionscript-3, path-finding, starling-framework

I wanted to randomly generate a new 2d array (my map) and to ensure that it always has at least 1 path from the start point to the end point.

Right now I have a static grid and have my pathfinding algorithm working properly.  My question is what is the best approach to develop this? What is the easiest way to create the grid and iterate through it to ensure a path is open?

I think my worst-case scenario will be to randomly generate one and path find then if false returned just randomly generate another, but this is very inefficient.  Please help!

Comment: This is typically referred to as "Maze Generation" you should be able to find various implementations in an assortment of languages including ActionScript.

Comment: agh thank you- I knew there must have been a specific name for it.  Thanks - i'll do some research now :)

Comment: This might help:
http://www.dauntless.be/astar/

Comment: Much appreciated! I have it set up now, just need to figure out how to generate a less populated map (with multiple paths) vs a fully populated map (with 1 path)

Comment: @Lagoo87 I've typically done this in a very "cheap" way by randomly removing a few walls in the otherwise complete maze.